# IPTABLES Limiting destination based on source?

Tags: centos, iptables, firewall

I am trying to have a bridge firewall between my network and IPMIs. I want to be able to limit the allowable destinations, e.g. IP x.x.x.x has access to x.x.y.y and x.x.y.z but no others while IP address y.x.x.y has access to y.y.x.x and y.y.x.z but no others, is there a way to do this through IP tables?

Comment: Of course; this is trivial. What have you tried so far and what does your current firewall look like?

Comment: I just scrapped it since it wasn't working as I wanted it to. The bridge server should be invisible.

Comment: So you want an invisible (level 2) bridge with a level 3 firewall on it?